# insert mysql select query with php, empty variable?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the query I'm trying to insert into a table in MYSQL

```
$query1 = "SELECT close FROM stocks WHERE the_date = '$the_date' AND ticker = '$ticker' ";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
```

I managed to print it out like this:

```
while($price = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
  echo "Price: ".$price['close']."<br /></h2>";
     }
```

And I tried inserting with this:

```
$query3 = "INSERT INTO transactions (trans_ID,the_date,client_ID,ticker,shares,price,buy)
           VALUES (\"$trans_ID\",\"$the_date\",client_ID,\"$ticker\", 
            $shares,$price,$buy)";
```

But the error message on the page said this:
"Query failed : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1)' at line 3" which is weird cause that's just where my html/head tags are.

So the I tried to do this:

```
var_dump($price);
```

and got this: bool(false)

so how do i make it so I can insert $price??
i looked up some stuff about inserting arrays, implodes, serializing, but I can't seem to get it to work?

thanks!

Comment: How does the code look like where you try to execute the $query3 ?

Comment: it's basically just the insert query. 
$query3 = "INSERT INTO transactions (trans_ID,the_date,client_ID,ticker,shares,price,buy)
           VALUES ('$trans_ID','$the_date','client_ID','$ticker', 
   '$shares','$price','$buy')";
above it i have it printing the results for $variables in html and below it i have a SELECT query to print out a table of results. would it help if i post up the entire code?

Comment: ($price = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
  echo "Price: ".$price['close']."<br /></h2>";
  }

var_dump($price);

$query3 = "INSERT INTO transactions (trans_ID,the_date,client_ID,ticker,shares,price,buy)
           VALUES (\"$trans_ID\",\"$the_date\",client_ID,\"$ticker\", 
   $shares,$price,$buy)"; 

$result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error()); 

/* Performing SQL SELECT query */
$query4 = "SELECT * FROM transactions ORDER BY trans_ID ";
$result = mysql_query($query4) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be like

`$query3 = "INSERT INTO transactions (trans_ID,the_date,client_ID,ticker,shares,price,buy)
           VALUES ('$trans_ID','$the_date','$client_ID','$ticker', 
            '$shares','$price','$buy')";`

But also do'nt forget to use `mysql_real_escape_string` on all those variables in query.

Comment: ah, thanks. that takes care of the syntax and prints me a table of results. but the value of $price is still void. its 0.00 in the table. how to i get it to actually pass the value of the SELECT for $price?

Comment: echo your query `$query3` before inserting in db and check whether query has proper price set or not. if it is proper then check datatype for column `price`

Comment: echo query 3? do you mean query 1? because query 3 is the insert query. And also, i suspected that the problem was with the price so I did a var dump with $price and that was empty. however when i echoed the price with $price['close'] it worked. i guess i just dont know how to take the result of query1 as $price and make it insertable?

Comment: ok you mean you want to pass `$price['close']` in insert query.
`$query3 = "INSERT INTO transactions (trans_ID,the_date,client_ID,ticker,shares,price,buy) VALUES ('$trans_ID','$the_date','$client_ID','$ticker', '$shares','".$price['close']."','$buy')";`

Comment: thanks! it wasn't working so i just stuck it in my while statement with the previous echo and the price registers now. for future reference though, since it is a single record. doing $price = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1) should give me the same results as using the while statement right? i tried taking it out of the while statement before and i just got errors with the echo so i just left it. thanks again though!!

Comment: Yes right. You don't need to use while if it is single record. welcome :)